# How to put in angular template to check if a specific array contains an object with property that equals to some value?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following in Angular:

```
<div *ngIf="myarrayContainsEating('Chocolate')">Chocolate Is Good</div>
```

In my component, I have:

```
myarray = [{'name':'Charles', 'age':25, 'eating':'Vanilla'}, {'name':'Joseph', 'age':18, 'eating':'Banana'}]

myArrayContainsEating(food) {

  let chocolateExists = false;
  for(var i = 0; myarray.length; i++) {
    if(myarray[i].eating == 'Chocolate') {
       chocolateExists = true;
    }
  }
  return chocolateExists;
}
```

The problem is, when I have a button where I hit it and make it so that Charles is eating 'Chocolate', it does not show the 'Chocolate Is Good' text I expect. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: What does `myarrayContainsEating` do?

Comment: @NicholasK Updated original post, just returns a boolean whether if found a value of 'Chocolate'.

Comment: Your if condition is incorrect. Change it to `if (myarray[i].eating === "Chocolate") { ... }`. Also, your current `myarray` doesn't have any object with the *eating* key whose value is chocolate.

Comment: @NicholasK I intentionally did not have any object with the eating key whose value is chocolate. I want to make it so that if somebody hit a button that later set say 'Charles' to be eating 'chocolate' or a new user is added that is eating 'chocolate', that the template would auto update to show the text.

Comment: Included a complete answer that explains all the issues at the moment - let me know your thoughts..

Comment: It’s unfortunate that nobody actually mentions that calling a method from your template is quite bad practice...

Comment: @MikeOne is it for performance reasons or what is the alternative you would say? Are you suggesting pipes or some other 'better' way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes for performance reasons. A pipe would be the recommend approach..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fixing your solution

Some problems with your code were already mentioned in other answers. Another thing to remind you of is the way you modify the `eating` property: You have to make sure to replace the array with a new array, each time an entry changes. Else the Change Detector will not pick up your changes.

You could do it like this:

**Template**

```
<div *ngIf="myarrayContainsEating('Chocolate')">Chocolate Is Good</div>

<button (click)="charlesEatChoc()">Make Charles eat Chocolate</button>
```

**TS**

```
myarray = [{'name':'Charles', 'age':25, 'eating':'Vanilla'}, {'name':'Joseph', 'age':18, 'eating':'Banana'}]

myarrayContainsEating(food) {
   return this.myarray.some(entry => entry.eating === food); // Check if any "eating" property is equal to food
}

charlesEatChoc() {
  this.myarray = this.myarray.map(entry => // This returns a new array (!!!IMPORTANT!!!)
     entry.name === 'Charles' // Map the entry if it matches your condition
        ? {...entry, eating: 'Chocolate'} // If it does, create a new one with the altered eating property
        : entry // If not, return the entry itself without modification
  );
}
```

Here is [a working Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-veias1)

### Cleaner solution

Calling a function inside an expression binding is not a good practice in Angular, since the Change Detector will have to rerun those methods each time there might have been a change. A cleaner way is to either hold a variable and change it accordingly (reactive apporach) or use a pipe.

**Component template**

```
<div *ngIf="myarray | containsFood:'Chocolate'">Chocolate Is Good</div>

<button (click)="charlesEatChoc()">Make Charles eat Chocolate</button>
```

**Component TS**

```
myarray = [{'name':'Charles', 'age':25, 'eating':'Vanilla'}, {'name':'Joseph', 'age':18, 'eating':'Banana'}]

charlesEatChoc() {
  this.myarray = this.myarray.map(entry => // This returns a new array (!!!IMPORTANT!!!)
     entry.name === 'Charles' // Map the entry if it matches your condition
        ? {...entry, eating: 'Chocolate'} // If it does, create a new one with the altered eating property
        : entry // If not, return the entry itself without modification
  );
}
```

**Pipe TS**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'containsFood'
})
export class ContainsFoodPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: Array<any>, food:string): boolean {
     return value.some(entry => entry.eating === food); // Check if any "eating" property is equal to food
  }

}
```

Again, another [working Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6j2dq)

Answer (score 2):

Your final method should look like:

```
myArrayContainsEating(food) {
   let chocolateExists = false;
   for (let i = 0; i < this.myarray.length; i++) {
      if (this.myarray[i].eating == food) {
         chocolateExists = true;
      }
   }
   return chocolateExists;
}
```

---

The following are the issues with your code:

1. Your if condition is incorrect. Change it to:

   ```
   if (myarray[i].eating === food) { 
      ... 
   }
   ```

   You need to access the *eating* property of *each* object. Nevertheless, the `myArrayContainsEating(...)` will still return
   false as there is no object in `myArray` array that has an object
   whose *eating* key contains the value chocolate. Thereby, the
   `<div>` will not be displayed.
2. Also, you are missing a terminal condition in your loop:

   ```
   for(let i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
      ...
   }
   ```
3. Next, you need to use the parameter passed in the method i.e `food` to evaluate in the `if` expression.

---

Alternatively, you could easily just do:

```
myArrayContainsEating(food) {
   return this.myarray.find(e => e.eating === food);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for function is bad.
You should traverse myarray[i].eating and not myarray.eating

```
myArrayContainsEating(food) {
  let chocolateExists = false;
  for(var i = 0; myarray.length; i++) {
    if(myarray[i].eating == 'Chocolate') {
       chocolateExists = true;
    }
  }
  return chocolateExists;
}
```